# Swift3 - how convert UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar> to UnsafeMutablePointer<utsname>

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm migrating Swift 2.x project to Swift 3.

I have problem with converting `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<utsname>` in Swift 3 syntax.

**Swift 2.x**:

```
(ptr: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>) -> DeviceTypes in
        uname(UnsafeMutablePointer<utsname>(ptr.baseAddress))
```

Comment: What is your issue "I have problem"?

Comment: Have you tried ["withMemoryRebound"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafepointer/2430863-withmemoryrebound)

Comment: @user28434 Yes, but I didn't understand how to make equivalent code using withMemoryRebound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3:**

```
(ptr: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<CChar>) -> DeviceTypes in

        guard let pointer = ptr.baseAddress?.withMemoryRebound(to: utsname.self, capacity: 1, { ptr in
            return ptr
        }) else {
            return DeviceTypes.unrecognized
        }
        uname(pointer)
```